# Automatically Attach Process When Debugging WPF (C#) Project in Visual Studio 22

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

We have a WPF app with several projects. One of the projects is a launcher to start other projects. It works well, except for debugging. Since they are different processes, breakpoints do not get hit. I have to attach the process manually everytime I launch the debugger. This is really annoying and a time waster. Is there a way to automatically attach the process when I debug?

Comment: Did you try to call [Debugger.Launch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) in the process to be debugged?

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft Child Process Debugging Power Tool 2022 (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsdbgplat.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool2022) extension to automatically attach to child processes.

See additional info here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/introducing-the-child-process-debugging-power-tool/